# Azure Application Registration: App Domain

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a request to register an application in my Azure tenant.
The request includes info on the App Domain and Redirect URL.

After registering the app, I gave the app name, app id, and client secret to the requestor.
He came back and said that he can see the redirect URL when he looked up the app ID but the App Domain field is still blank.

I do not see this field option when registering an application. Does anyone know where this is located or how it is configured?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom domain in azure ad under the custom domains tab in the portal.

Just the click on the add custom domain can fill the subsequent form.
[image]

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain) on custom domains.